# Sharepoint permissions at document level? Probably a stupid question

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

Disclaimer: Please forgive me if this is a silly thing to ask but I work in a small company and our sharepoint build was outsourced and not done very well, and I'm the closest thing we have to an admin, and I'm just trying to understand what is/isn't possible when it comes to controlling access to our sharepoint content so we can have a clear idea of what we want to do when the time comes to rebuild.

So, my question: we have a set of documents that are stored in a series of libraries. We have several different types of users, who are bound by different levels of contract/NDA.

Some users need access to all our documentation, some need access to most of our documentation and some need access to only some of it.

At the moment, we have them divided into 3 separate user groups, who each have access to only their own library. and we populate each with all of the documents that each group needs access to, which means that a large sub-set of the documents are duplicated across multiple libraries.

[image: current set up]

EG: user group 1 has access to folder 1 only. User group 2 has access to folder 2 only, etc etc.

This is problematic as we end up with version control issues as people may update a doc in one location and forget that it is also in the one or more of the others.

What I would like is to find a way to maintain only 1 set of documents and be able to control who has access to it at the document level.

Now, I can see how it could be managed by splitting the documents up into separate folders by access level, and it would look something like below:

[image: folders by access level]

However, this just doesn't make any sense in terms of our actual content; it's not that user group 1 needs all the legal content and user group 2 needs all the commercial content, and UG3 needs technical. It's that UG1 needs all the legal, commercial and technical content, UG2 needs most of the above, and UG3 is only allowed access to a smaller amount of high level documentation on each.

In real life, it looks something more like this:

[image: folders with doc tiers]

So ideally, I'd like a solution for permissions that looks something like this:

[image: folders and permissions]

In my head, this involves creating permission levels and applying them to the individual documents, for eg: Document #123 can be access by permission level Y, which means user groups 1 & 2 can access it, but not user group 3.

[image: permission levels and usergroups]

Is this even something that is possible to do? Does it make sense? If I'm way off base, I'd love any suggestions on how else we could/should manage this.

NB: I'm not asking for anyone to tell me the detail of *how* to achieve this, as that's well beyond my capability and we'd definitely be outsourcing the doing, I'm more just looking to understand *what* it is we should be getting done when we do get it done, so we don't end up with a substandard solution again.

Huge thanks in advance!
L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to set unique permissions for documents. And you don’t want to put a document in different places to cause a version error.

In my opinion, you first divide users into three separated user groups. Then set unique permissions for individual documents. For example, document1 can be accessed by group1, document2 can be accessed by group1 and group2, etc. Using folders to classify documents cannot meet your requirement.

Update:

1.Select the file -> Manage access -> Advanced.
[image]

[image]

2.Stop Inheriting Permissions -> Remove permissions of users you do not want, grant permissions for users you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Emily, Yes, this sounds like exactly what I want to do. So it is possible?

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answer. This is super helpful and exactly what I needed!